# PHP $_SESSION not registering in android webview

Tags: php, android, session, android-webview

We have created an app that has our website as webview. While trying to log in to  our website, we found out that PHP $_SESSION is not getting registered, whereas other PHP variables are working fine ($_POST,$_GET). We have enabled cookies, javascript on our mainActivity java file but still no avail. Here is the MainActivity Java file.

```
package com.example.app;  

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.webkit.WebSettings; 
import android.webkit.WebStorage; 
import android.webkit.CookieManager; 


public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private WebView webView;
        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") 
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progressBar.setMax(100);
            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.simpleWebView);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientDemo());
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClientDemo());
              WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
  settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); 
  settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true); 

CookieManager.getInstance();


            webView.loadUrl("https://ecitizen.in/");
        }
        private class WebViewClientDemo extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progressBar.setProgress(100);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        }       
    }
        private class WebChromeClientDemo extends WebChromeClient {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        else {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       return true;
    }
}
```

Where i'm i going wrong.

Comment: Could it be in the PHP maybe? You have `session_start` and you're logging errors?

Comment: whats the error you are getting?

Comment: We have already declared session_start in our php pages. Moreover, our website working in the web flawlessly.

Comment: @prasannaputtaswamy, there is no error that's popping out. Just the session is not getting registered.

Comment: Okay, problem resolved. It was due to unexpected session loss in mobile web. Thanks for all the help extended

Answer (score 0):

As @Abracadaver wrote, the `session_start()` which is required to make `$_SESSION` work should be missing in the PHP part.

Comment: We have already declared session_start in our php pages. Moreover, our website working in the web flawlessly.